# Varnish Turpentine - Failed to apply the VCL

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, turpentine

I've installed Varnish Turpintine on our staging site by following the instructions on the [Magento-Turpintine wiki](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/Installation).

Our site is on Ubuntu 14.04, NGINX, varnish-4.0.3m,  Turpentine v0.6.5, Magento 1.9.2.

These are my `DAEMON_OPTS` in `/etc/default/varnish`

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -p cli_buffer=16384 \
             -p feature=+esi_ignore_other_elements \
             -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

I installed the turpentine module successfully, only really changing the config for the Secret Varnish Authentication Key with the `\n` appended, URL Blacklist and enabling debug info.

When I tried saving my configuration I got the bellow error:

```
Failed to apply the VCL to 127.0.0.1:6082: Got unexpected response code from Varnish: 106 Message from VCC-compiler: directors are now in directors VMOD. ('input' Line 27 Pos 1) director default round-robin { ########---------------------- Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2 VCL compilation failed
```

This is what I have in the Turpentine generate `var/default.vcl` file:

```
vcl 4.0;
C{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
long a = lrand48();
long b = lrand48();
long c = lrand48();
long d = lrand48();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx",
a,
b & 0xffff,
(b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
(c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
(c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
d
);
return;
}
}C
import std;
director default round-robin {
{
.backend = {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 300s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}
}
}
director admin round-robin {
{
.backend = {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 21600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 21600s;
}
}
```

I was seemingly able to fix this by creating the `custom_include.vcl` file from `version-4.vcl`  as it was missing

```
cp app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/misc/version-4.vcl app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/misc/custom_include.vcl
```

But now when I try to save the configuration I get a new error:

```
Failed to apply the VCL to 127.0.0.1:6082: Varnish data to write over length limit by 749 characters
```

This seems to be related to the `-p cli_buffer=16384` which I set in the `DAEMON_OPTS` at `/etc/default/varnish`.  When I try increasing this I still get the same error but with a different limit.

```
Failed to apply the VCL to 127.0.0.1:6082: Varnish data to write over length limit by 8941 characters.
```

I have nothing in `magento/var/log/` or `/var/log/varnish/` for Varnish. I tried chacking the Varnish Admin to see if there was anything wrong with the cli_buffer but could see nothing of note.

```
$ sudo varnishadm
varnish> param.show cli_buffer
200        
cli_buffer
        Value is: 16k [bytes]
        Default is: 8k
        Minimum is: 4k

        Size of buffer for CLI command input.
        You may need to increase this if you have big VCL files and use
        the vcl.inline CLI command.
        NB: Must be specified with -p to have effect.
```

Thanks in advance for any advice suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have gotten this working by applying a fix I found of [GitHub ticket 915](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/pull/915).

First off the fix I applied for my first error was misleading so I removed the file I created.

```
rm app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/misc/custom_include.vcl
```

Then I merged the [devel branch of the Magento-Turpintine repo](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/tree/devel) with my Magento project as suggested in the [GitHub Ticket 915](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/pull/915).

Now when I save the Turpintine Config / apply the Varnish config I got no error messages.

Although the site does not seem to have sped up a great deal, how can I ensure varnish is working as it is supposed to.

**UPDATE**
I was able to ensure Varnish was working by running varnishstat, if the Hitrate avg is greater than 0 it means the cache is being hit.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing. I just installed the latest version from the `devel` branch to fix a very similar problem. To check if Varnish is caching you could use either of the following varnishtop commands, if you have access to the server.

```
/usr/bin/varnishtop -i RxURL
/usr/bin/varnishtop -i RxHeader -C -I \^HOST
```

Comment: both say something like `-i: "RxURL" matches zero tags`. Does this mean it's not working?  Do you know what `varnishtop -i` is doing?  when i run `varnishtop` on it's own without the `-i` flag I get a lot of info

Comment: Not sure, I always got out with either of them when browsing the site.